# How to convert time from character to time and group by hour

Tags: r

Need to convert character data as a time into actual time and group by hour

```
library(dplyr) 
library(stringr)
library(lubridate)
library(chron)
test <- read.csv("O:/Commercial Team/Customer Business Unit/ECOMMERCE and DIGITAL/9. TEAM/4_M_APPLEYARD.GEO.csv", header = TRUE)
colnames(test)
time <- str_split(test$ProcessedDate, " ", simplify = TRUE)
time2 <- c(time[,2])
```

Comment: where exactly are you stuck?

Answer (score 1):

Check out `strptime` [here](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.0/topics/strptime). I don't know what your data looks like so here's an example:

```
z <- strptime('2019-06-4 09:32:14', format = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M%:S')
```

Which gives output `[1] "2019-06-04 09:32:14 CEST"`.

You can edit format as you like.

Edit:
It is based in seconds, so `z + 3600 = "2019-06-04 10:32:14 CEST"`

Answer (score 1):

You could create an hour column and use `group_by()`:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

df <- tibble(ProcessedDate = sample(seq.POSIXt(from = as_datetime("2018-01-01 00:00:00"),
                                        to = as_datetime("2018-12-31 23:59:59"),
                                        by = "sec"), size = 1000, replace = TRUE),
             placeholder_value = rlnorm(n = 1000))

df2 <- df %>% 
  mutate(Processed_hour = hour(ProcessedDate),
         Processed_minute = minute(ProcessedDate),
         Processed_second = second(ProcessedDate)) %>% 
  group_by(Processed_hour) %>%
  summarise(sum = sum(placeholder_value)) 

print(df2, n = Inf)

ggplot(df2, aes(x = as_factor(Processed_hour), y = sum)) +
  geom_col()
```

Comment: This isn't working because the graph stays the same whether I use ProcessedDate or ReceivedDate (which are two different date columns)

Comment: I don't follow, but I believe sharing some of your input data would be helpful - the date column that is. I just created random datetime values in the column `ProcessedDate`, but I don't know the format of your datetime variable.

Comment: It is a csv file and the format is text or in R character.  I cannot share input data due to confidential,

Comment: What I mean is that I would like to see the time format - as it is in the .csv file. What is the exact way that time is represented in the file?

Answer (score 1):

Essentially a simpler version of larsoevlisen's answer as I think you can do everything with lubridate (but hard to tell without a sample of your data):

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

#create imaginary data set for this answer
#skip this step if you already have your data
df <- tibble(yourtimestamp = c("2019-06-04 11:20", "2019-06-04 11:25", "2019-06-04 12:00"))

#convert your timestamp vector to POSIX
df$yourtimestamp <- ymd_hm(df$yourtimestamp)
#the function you use here depends on what order the parts of your time stamp are, 
#so for example if your character timestamp is US style: month, day, year 
#such as 
#06/20/2019 11:20 then use mdy_hm() instead
#or if it was UK style 20/06/2019 11:20 then use dmy_hm() etc
#or if it contains seconds such as 06/20/2019 11:20:47 use mdy_hms()

#get hour
df$just_the_hour <- hour(df$yourtimestamp)

#group by hour and summarise
by_hour <- group_by(df, just_the_hour)
s <- summarise(by_hour, num_events = n())
s
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 2 x 2
  just_the_hour num_events
          <int>      <int>
1            11          2
2            12          1
```

Comment: output looks better and simple but I got an error: Warning message:
All formats failed to parse. No formats found.

Comment: ah, that sounds like you may need to modify the `ymd_hm()` part. If your time stamp is say US date format "06/20/2019 11:20" then try `mdy_hm` as your lubridate function. Alternatively lubridate is clever enough to skip the POSIX conversion and can sometimes extract the hour from your character version.

Comment: Try `dmy_hm()` if its "04/06/2019 11:20" or  `dmy_hms()` if the stamp includes seconds "04/06/2019 11:20:50"

Comment: df <- tibble(timestamp = c("test$dReceivedDate")) - is this right?  I've changed to UK format with seconds now but still getting the same error. Thanks

Comment: try `test$dReceivedDatePOSIX <- dmy_hm(test$dReceivedDate)`

Comment: df <- tibble(timestamp = c(test$dReceivedDate))
Error: All columns in a tibble must be 1d or 2d objects:
* Column `timestamp` is NULL

Comment: I am only using the `tibble(timestamp blah blah)` to create an imaginary data set. Skip that step and just try the `dmy_hm(test$dReceivedData)` on whatever vector your timestamps live in